# Getting 404 on other machine, Why?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am developing an Asp.Net Core 3.1 API, Everything is working fine on my machine as well as other developer's machine when we are running the API locally from visual studio. We are able to hit the request and getting the proper response.

But another developer just cloned the repo and got the latest code by using `git pull`. So he has the same source code.

When he is running the project locally from a visual studio and trying to access the HTTP GET methods, he is getting an HTTP 404 error.

He is able to call the one controller's methods and for other controller's HTTP GET methods, he is getting 404 error. and Url is valid.

I have added `AllowAnonymous` on the controller also, there is no other information in browser's console except the 404 error also.

So what can be the issue?

Update:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using FxBatchProcCommon.Logger;
using FxBatchProcessing.InstructionValidation.Interfaces;
using FxBatchProcessing.InstructionValidation.Rules;
using FxBatchProcessing.Payment.Interfaces;
using FxBatchProcessing.Payment.Xml;
using FxBatchProcessing.Repository;
using ISOXMLValidationApi.Repositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

namespace ISOXMLValidationApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private const string _apiVersion = "v1";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddScoped<IISOXMLValidationRepository, ISOXMLValidationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IDBUtilRepository, DBUtilRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRuleManager, RuleManager>();
            services.AddScoped<IFieldRepository, FieldRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IErrorRepository, ErrorRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IBatchProcessorConfigRepository, BatchProcessorConfigRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPaymentCollectionConverter, PaymentCollectionConverter>();
            services.AddScoped<IInstructionRepository, InstructionRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICurrencyRepository, CurrencyRepository>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Version = _apiVersion,
                    Title = "ISOXMLValidation API",
                    Description = "ISOXMLValidationApi"
                });
                options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

                // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });

                options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
            app.UseSwagger(c => { c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json"; });

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
                options.SwaggerEndpoint($"../swagger/{_apiVersion}/swagger.json", $"MyProject API {_apiVersion}");
                options.DisplayRequestDuration(); // Controls the display of the request duration (in milliseconds) for "Try it out" requests.  
            });
        }
    }
}


namespace ISOXMLValidationApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class ISOXMLValidationController : ControllerBase, Helper.ILogger
    {
        //private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        //private readonly IISOXMLValidationRepository _iSOXMLValidationRepository;
        ILogger<Helper.ILogger> _logger;
        private IRuleManager _ruleManager;
        //private PaymentInfo _payment;
        //private IBatchProcessorConfigRepository _batchProcessorConfigRepository;
        //private IPaymentCollectionConverter _paymentCollectionConverter;
        public ISOXMLValidationController(/*IConfiguration configuration, IISOXMLValidationRepository iSOXMLValidationRepository,*/
            ILogger<Helper.ILogger> logger, IRuleManager ruleManager/*, PaymentInfo payment,*/
            /*IBatchProcessorConfigRepository batchProcessorConfigRepository, IPaymentCollectionConverter paymentCollectionConverter*/)
        {
            //_iSOXMLValidationRepository = iSOXMLValidationRepository;
            _logger = logger;
            //_configuration = configuration;
            _ruleManager = ruleManager;
            //_payment = payment;
            //_batchProcessorConfigRepository = batchProcessorConfigRepository;
            //_paymentCollectionConverter = paymentCollectionConverter;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Method to get all the validation rules for currency and country
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="currencyCode"> default value ""</param>
        /// <param name="countryId">default value 0</param>
        /// <returns>all validate rules for currency and country</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetValidationRules")]
        public ActionResult GetValidationRules(string currencyCode = "", int countryId = 0)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"GetValidationRules currencyCode {currencyCode} countryId {countryId}");
                IEnumerable<IFieldRuleConfig> ccyConfigRules = _ruleManager.GetValidationRules(
                    new CurrencyCountry { CurrencyCode = currencyCode, CountryFk = countryId });

                return Ok(ccyConfigRules);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
```

}

[image]

Comment: Can you put your startup.cs and your controllers codes?

Comment: Are you missing IIS hosting, virtual directory mapping or HOST entry to the local machine for the application URL?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Its the exact same code, which I am using on my machine, the other developer is also using the same code without making any changes

Comment: Code is same but the way you run the code might be different. Is the web project configured to run on IISExpress or some IIS hosted web application?

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi I have added in the question, please check

Comment: What api address do you call that doesn't work? /api/ISOXMLValidation/GetValidationRules ?

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi yes its not working

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have added the project properties screenshot to the question

Comment: Change your controller route to [Route("api/[controller]")] and then call /api/ISOXMLValidation/GetValidationRules

Comment: I tried, it's not working @ArsalanValoojerdi

Comment: @ArsalanValoojerdi I have solved the issue, but still unclear on the root cause of the issue? please refer my answer

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please refer my answer and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, but I still have no clue why it was not working. I am writing the workaround below, please let me know if someone knows what was causing the issue?

So on the **other machine developer was running the solution from Visual Studio 2017, So I ran it using Visual Studio 2019, and then it started working as expected**.

But after that, I tried to run the project using visual studio 2017 on my machine, and its working as expected on my machine.

1. On his machine, it's working as expected on VS 2019, but not in VS
   2017.
2. But on my machine its working on both 2019 and 2017.

So please let me know what can be the root cause?
and how to make it work as expcted in VS 2017 on his machine?